# Finding possible values of $k$ such that the graph of the function is disconnected.

Tags: real-analysis

This is a practice question I stumbled upon while studying for the math GRE.

If $k$ is a real number, define $f$ to be $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=k$. If the graph of $f$ is not a connected subset of the plne, then the value of $k$

(A) could be $-1$

(B) must be $0$

(C) must be $1$

(D) could be less than $1$ and greater than $-1$

(E) must be less than $-1$ or greater than $1$

The answer is (E), but why? Obviously, $k$ could be less than $-1$ or greater than $1$ since those values are outside of the range of the sine function, but why must it be? If a set is disconnected, it can be expressed as the union of more than one disjoint set. In terms of a graph, I am interpreting it to mean that the graph is continuous. $\lim_{x \to 0}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist, but intuitively, I would think that there would be a most one value of $k$ that would make f be continuous. However, (E) would imply that every value in the range of the sine function would connect the set. What key point am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

A connected set is one that cannot be represented as the union of two or more disjoint nonempty open subsets. If $f(0)$ is in $[-1,1]$, the graph cannot be written as the union of two disjoint open sets. This is because for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $y\neq0$ such that $|f(0)-sin(1/y)| < \epsilon$